# How to pass variable that's a dictionary into Ansible Role?

Tags: yaml, ansible

I want to pass some values into an Ansible role, but I can't find any examples in the docs that show how to pass in a variable that's a dictionary.

Here is what I'd like to pass in, but my YAML syntax is off:

```
roles:
  - { role: postgresql,
          postgresql_users:
            - name: dev_user
              pass: dev_pass
              encrypted: no,
            - name: test_user
              pass: test_pass
              encrypted: no
          postgresql_databases: ['dev', 'test'],
          postgresql_user_privileges:
            - name: dev_user
              db: dev
              priv: "ALL"
            - name: test_user
              db: test
              priv: "ALL"
          tags: ['postgres'] 
      }
```

What is the proper YAML syntax for passing in these variables which have dictionary values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should be closer to this:

```
roles:
  - { role: postgresql,
      postgresql_users: [
        { name: "dev_user",
          pass: "dev_pass",
          encrypted: "no" },
        { name: "test_user",
          pass: "test_pass",
          encrypted: "no" }
      ],
      postgresql_databases: ['dev', 'test'],
      postgresql_user_privileges:[
        { name: "dev_user",
            db: "dev",
            priv: "ALL" },
        { name: "test_user",
            db: "test",
            priv: "ALL"}
      ],
      tags: ['postgres'] 
    }
```

Note that I assumed "dev_user" et al. were strings. If you want variables, you need `name: "{{ dev_user }}"`